# First entry in JSON Object not getting set in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I am having a weird problem which can't find a solution to.
I am little new to javascript, so spare me.
I am trying to save entries of a form in json object. So whenever save button is clicked the current values of the form are saved into the json object <s>with numeric index</s>, but the problem is that the first set of entries is not getting saved to the object, the first index is also not available.
Hover it seems to work fine from there on i.e. 2, 3, ..., n are getting save correctly. Here is the code a bit ugly though.

[image]
[image]

```js
let data = new Object;
let serial = 1;
let bookName;
let publication;
let mrp;
let qty;
let bookCode;
let purchasePrice;
let discount;
let date;
let invoiceNo;
let refNo;
let supplier;
let subject;
let author;
let shelfPos;



function setData(index) {
 data[index] = {
   'bookName'     : bookName,
   'publication'  : publication,
   'mrp'          : mrp,
   'qty'          : qty,
   'bookCode'     : bookCode,
   'purchasePrice': purchasePrice,
   'discount'     : discount,
   'date'         : date,
   'invoiceNo'    : invoiceNo,
   'refNo'        : refNo,
   'supplier'     : supplier,
   'subject'      : subject,
   'author'       : author,
   'shelfPos'     : shelfPos
  };
}
function getTemplate(index) {
 return template = `<tr>
     <td>${index}</td>
     <td>${bookName}</td>
     <td>${publication}</td>
     <td>${mrp}</td>
     <td>${qty}</td>
     <td>${bookCode}</td>
     <td>${purchasePrice}</td>
     <td>${discount}</td>
    </tr>`;
}


$(function(){
 setData(serial);
 $('.entry_preview').css('max-height', $(window).height());
 $("#datepicker").datepicker();

 $('.btn-add').on('click', function() {
  bookName       = $('input[name=bookName]').val();
  publication    = $('select[name=publication]').find(':selected').text();
  mrp            = $('input[name=mrp]').val();
  qty            = $('input[name=qty]').val();
  bookCode       = $('input[name=code]').val();
  purchasePrice  = $('input[name=purchasePrice]').val();
  discount       = $('input[name=discount]').val();
  date           = $('input[name=date').val();
  invoiceNo      = $('input[name=invoiceNo').val();
  refNo          = $('input[name=refNo').val();
  supplier       = $('select[name=supplier').find(':selected').text();
  subject        = $('input[name=subject').val();
  author         = $('input[name=author').val();
  shelfPos       = $('input[name=shelfPos').val();
  $('.entry_preview tbody').append(getTemplate(serial));
  setData(serial);
  serial++;
 });


 function sendData(jsonData) {
  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
  var request; 

  request = new XMLHttpRequest()
  request.open("POST", "db.php", true)
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
  request.send(jsonString)
 }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Roboto;
  background-color: #fff; }

.top-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #292c31; }
  .top-bar .header {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #22a3a9; }

.form {
  min-width: 1000px;
  max-width: 1366px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: ''; }
  .form .action_type {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-color: #292c31;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0; }
    .form .action_type .action {
      min-width: 150px;
      border-radius: 5000px;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      margin: 10px 20px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #22a3a9; }
      .form .action_type .action [type="radio"]:checked,
      .form .action_type .action [type="radio"]:not(:checked) {
        position: absolute;
        left: -9999px; }
      .form .action_type .action [type="radio"]:checked + label,
      .form .action_type .action [type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label {
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 28px;
        cursor: pointer;
        line-height: 20px;
        display: inline-block; }
      .form .action_type .action [type="radio"]:checked + label:before,
      .form .action_type .action [type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        border-radius: 100%;
        background: #fff; }
      .form .action_type .action [type="radio"]:checked + label:after,
      .form .action_type .action [type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
        content: '';
        width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
        background: #292c31;
        position: absolute;
        top: 1px;
        left: 1px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
        transition: all 0.2s ease; }
      .form .action_type .action [type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
        -ms-transform: scale(0);
        transform: scale(0); }
      .form .action_type .action [type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1); }
  .form table {
    float: left; }
  .form td {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px; }
  .form label,
  .form select {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #5A5A5A; }
  .form input[type=text],
  .form select {
    border-radius: 500px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #22a3a9; }
  .form .td-short {
    max-width: 90px; }
  .form .td-short:nth-child(3) {
    padding-right: 20px; }
  .form input[name=qty],
  .form input[name=mrp] {
    display: block;
    width: 90px; }
  .form input[name="barcode"] {
    width: 440px; }
  .form button {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #22a3a9;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 500px;
    cursor: pointer; }
  .form .btn-add {
    padding: 10px 88px; }
  .form .btn-clear {
    padding: 10px 68px; }

.entry_preview {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: auto;
  oaverflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: #fff; }

.entry_preview table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; }

.entry_preview table th {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #292c31;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  font-weight: 300; }

.entry_preview table tr {
  text-align: center; }

.entry_preview input[name=save] {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border-radius: 500px;
  background-color: #22a3a9;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Foundation for Sites</title>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css"> -->
</head>

<body>

  <div class="top-bar">
    <div class="header">Book Software</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    <!--      <div class="action_type">
      <div class="action">
       <input type="radio" name="entryType" value="newEntry" id="new_entry" value="newEntry"><label for="new_entry" >New Entry</label>
      </div>
      <div class="action">
       <input type="radio" name="entryType" value="updateEntry" id="update_entry" value="updateEntry"><label for="update_entry" >Edit Existing Entry</label>
      </div>
     </div> -->
    <table class="left">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><label>Ref. No.</label><input name="refNo" type="text"></td>
          <td><label>Invoice No.</label><input name="invoiceNo" type="text"></td>
          <td><label>Date</label><input name="bookCode" type="text" id="datepicker"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label>Supplier</label>
            <select name="supplierName">
       <option value="supplier-1" >Supplier-1</option>
       <option value="supplier-2" >Supplier-2</option>
       <option value="supplier-3" >Supplier-3</option>
       <option value="supplier-4" >Supplier-4</option>
       <option value="supplier-5" >Supplier-5</option>
      </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label>Publication</label>
            <select name="publication">
       <option value="publisher-1" >Publisher-1</option>
       <option value="publisher-2" >Publisher-2</option>
       <option value="publisher-3" >Publisher-3</option>
       <option value="publisher-4" >Publisher-4</option>
       <option value="publisher-5" >Publisher-5</option>
      </select>
          </td>
          <td><label>Discount</label><input disabled name="discount" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label>Book Name</label><input type="text" name="bookName"></td>
          <td class="td-short"><label>Qty</label><input name="qty" type="text"></td>
          <td class="td-short"><label>MRP</label><input type="text" name="mrp"></td>
          <td><label>Purchase Price</label><input name="purchasePrice" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label>Book Code</label><input name="code" type="text"></td>
          <td><label>Shelf Position</label><input name="shelfPos" type="text"></td>
          <td><label>&nbsp;</label><button class="btn-add"> + Add</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label>Subject</label><input name="subject" type="text"></td>
          <td><label>Author</label><input name="author" type="text"></td>
          <td><label>&nbsp;</label><button class="btn-clear">Clear Form</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="controls">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="entry_preview">
    <form id="invoice-form" action="db.php" method="post">
      <!-- <input type="submit" name="submit" value="save"> -->
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>S.No.</th>
            <th>Book Name</th>
            <th>Publication</th>
            <th>MRP</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Book Code</th>
            <th>Purchase Price</th>
            <th>Discount</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <input type="submit" name="save" value="save">
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>


  <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="js/vendor/what-input.js"></script> -->
  <!-- <script src="js/vendor/foundation.js"></script> -->
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: array index in javascript starts at `0`

Comment: sorry, but by numeric index i meant i am passing the index to the object. if that what you meant. I will edit the question

Comment: No ... `let serial = 1;` ... and you use `serial` in the call to `setData(serial);` ... which sets `data[index] = {... some big object ...}` ... so, you never fill `data[0]`

Comment: Yes it did work. But i thought we could set whatever index we want to make an assoc array. meaning that data[1] should be there. am i correct

Comment: I misunderstood, I thought you were saying the first entry in the array was empty

Comment: Yes, that is the problem, I know that array index starts with 0, But i dont want it that way tha's why i am passing index to it starting from 1 but it dosent takes index 1 but takes 2, 3 and so on. I am adding an image of output to the answer.